# what did the DisplayObject do with its "dispose" method in Starling?

Tags: dispose

I noticed that every displayObjects in Starling has dispose method, but i don't know about what has been done when I called its dispose() method.

I think I could make myself more clear to describe it by example:

### I defined a Class like this:

```
public class SubSprite extends Sprite
{
    private var img:Image;
    public function SubSprite()
    {
        img = new Image( assetsManager.getTexture("textureName") );
        addChild(img);
        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
    }
}
```

---

### and then I wrote the lines in the main class as follow:

`var mySprite:SubSprite = new SubSprite();
    addChild(mySprite);
    mySprite.dispose(); // what will be done by using this method?`

---

will the dispose method do these things listed? or which one will be done?

1. img.texture.dispose;
2. img.dispose;
3. img = null;
4. mySprite = null;
5. removeChild(img);
6. removeChild(mySprite);
7. mySprite.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);

Answer (score 0):

It removes all event listeners from the object, disposes its filter's resources, such as textures, vertex and index buffers of the object. Those buffers are used for rendering the object by means of GPU (Stage3D).